# How to create customer custom attribute for radio buttons in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7, customer-attribute, multiselect-attribute, checkbox

I want to create customer custom attributes with following types: 
1.radio buttons 
2.checkbox

Please provide me a solution to create customer custom attribute.

If the checkbox contains more than 3 options, then how the Boolean type is work.